# ImageView does not replace previously used Drawable in RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, imageview

I am using `ImageView` inside my custom Adapter class. The problem is my Adapter has 2 image views inside and I am using a "placeholder image" as a default image on them but when I try to populate my `RecyclerView` and `setImageResource()` using Adapter's `ViewHolder` it simply goes behind the default "placeholder image" instead of overwriting it. I am quite new to both Java and Android App Development so I don't know if the `setImageResource()` works different with Adapters.

Here's my code:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.itemView.setTag(product.get(position));

        holder.tvTitle.setText(product.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.tvDescription.setText(product.get(position).getDescription());

        //PROBLEM STARTS HERE
        //Set Status (getSale() returns bool)
        switch (product.get(position).getSale()?"sold":"available"){
            case "sold":
                holder.ivStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.sold);
                break;
            case "available":
                holder.ivStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.available);
                break;
        }

        //Set Product Image
        switch (product.get(position).getType()){
            case "Laptop":
                holder.ivProduct.setImageResource(R.drawable.laptop);
                break;
            case "LCD":
                holder.ivProduct.setImageResource(R.drawable.screen);
                break;
            case "USB":
                holder.ivProduct.setImageResource(R.drawable.memory);
                break;
            case "Hard Disk":
                holder.ivProduct.setImageResource(R.drawable.hdd);
                break;
        }


    }
```

In Both cases the switch-case works correctly and picks the right image resource but it simply places the image Resource behind placeholder image. how do I just overwrite the default image?

Comment: setImageResource should work like you use it. It would be helpful if you provide the piece of code where you set your default image. (include the xml of whatever item contains the ivStatus.

Comment: Thank you so much for asking to provide XML, I checked like 100 time if there was problem in XML but as soon as I tried to copy the part of Code I found out that I am using placeholder image as default as well as foreground. here's the XML of my image view: ```<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivStatus"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:foreground="@drawable/placeholder"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/placeholder" />```

Comment: you should also paste the code that provide information to adapter. it means how you setup your list. cause the simple switch with getting type is correct. there may be an issue in how you set the Type element in your data.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see both images because you set both background and foreground images on the `ImageView`

To solve this remove `android:foreground` from both `ImageViews` and leave the placeholder in `app:srcCompat`

So your `ImageView` should look like:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivStatus"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/placeholder" />
```

Comment: Yeah, I already admitted that. I somehow added foreground while using design view of Fragment and did not happen to notice it.

Comment: excuse me I didn't notice your admission, just looked at the layout at once happy coding :)